# How to install the more advanced version for 'libjetty9-java' in my debian?

Tags: debian, version

Show debian version in my pc:

```
lsb_release -a 
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 9.0 (stretch)
Release:    9.0
Codename:   stretch
```

Show libjetty9-java's version:

```
dpkg -l  libjetty9-java
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
ii  libjetty9-java 9.2.21-1+deb all          Java servlet engine and webserver
```

An app want to install more advanced version:

```
Depends: libjetty9-java (>= 9.4) but 9.2.21-1+deb9u1 is to be installed
```

How can i install libjetty9-java (>= 9.4) in my stretch ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn’t a generalisable answer, but in this particular case, you can download and install [the Debian 10 version of the package](https://packages.debian.org/buster/libjetty9-java):

```
wget http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/j/jetty9/libjetty9-java_9.4.15-1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i libjetty9-java_9.4.15-1_all.deb
```

Its dependencies will already be satisfied on your system.